# Excel Vlookup doesn't work when using a cell index

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a simple business problem to solve. When I try to use the vlookup function to look for values based on userid.

```
=VLOOKUP(12345,'[Data copy.csv]users'!$A$1:$B$6605,2,FALSE)
```

userid = 12345
it returns the matching value.
However, when I use A2 instead of the real userid, I got the #NA value.
I have double checked the format of data, they are the same.

Comment: Sounds like A2 is actually text that looks like a number instead of a number?  If you do `=VLOOKUP(--A2,'[Data copy.csv]users'!$A$1:$B$6605,2,FALSE)` do you get the same result?

Comment: what is the raw underlying value of the content of cell A2? What do you see when you click on cell A2? And you're sure that it is not formatted as text? When A2 is selected press Alt-A-E-F, what happens then

Comment: Try this `=VLOOKUP(VALUE(A2),'[Data copy.csv]users'!$A$1:$B$6605,2,FALSE)`

Comment: It was the data problem. I converted A2 from txt to numeric and the problem was solved. thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It's common for Excel to treat numbers and numbers stored as text differently, even if the value is the same. Confusingly, simply changing the format of a cell from "Text" to "General" isn't enough to resolve this, and the number will still be treated as text.

You can troubleshoot this problem by doing something like `=A2=<Match>`, where  is the cell in Data Copy.csv that contains userID 12345. I suspect the formula will return a "FALSE", indicating that the two values are not the same.

You can resolve it in a number of ways, which will depend on exactly which value is the problem. Given that the match is in a .csv file, where you can't save data types as easily, your best bet will likely be to convert your Excel data to be the same data type as the .csv.